# Running into confusion try to integrate Twitter Bootstrap into a Google App Engine-driven webapp

Tags: python, css, google-app-engine, twitter-bootstrap

I'm unsure of how to get the two to work together.  I followed the instructions of how to set up Twitter Bootstrap but for some reason when I run the server locally I get 404s when I try to reference the css/js dirs.

I know that I could go and download Boilerplate but I was given this task of creating my own webapp by a boss/mentor as a general introduction to web development (I'm a noob), and I'd like to build as much of it from scratch as I can.  Just to help solidify my understanding of it all.

So here's what I've done so far:

I took the bootstrap directories (css, js, img) and put them in a folder called 'static' that I created in my application directory - the directory where my app.yaml file is.  Then, in my app.yaml file, I have:

```
handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: sorter.app

- url: /img/(.*\.(gif|png|jpg))
  static_files: static/img/\1
  upload: static/img/(.*\.(gif|png|jpg))

- url: /css
  static_dir: static/css

- url: /js
  mime_type: text/javascript
  static_dir: static/js
```

When I sync the app directory with google, it tells me that 8 static files were copied (there are 8 twitter bootstrap files).  Yet in my sorter.py file (sorter.app), I get 404s from all three of these:

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" >
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" >
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a catch-all url in the beginning of your app.yaml so all requests will be routed through your app instead of being served directly by GAE. Move the handler to the end of your handler list:

```
handlers:
- url: /css
  static_dir: static/css
...
- url: /.*
  script: sorter.app
```

Also, you might want to use absolute urls instead of relative ones in your html. For example `/css/bootstrap.min.css` will probably work better than `css/bootstrap.min.css`.

Comment: THANKS! can't believe I did not notice that.

Answer (score 2):

I use bootstrap with app engine.  My app.yaml file has a static handler.  I will update this answer as I find more differences.

```
handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static
```

My app.yaml file and static folder are in the root application directory.  My directory structure has static/css for the css folder.

My path is also slightly different than yours:

```
<link href="../static/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: thanks for the reply! so are you saying that you have the static handler, with the css/js/img dirs inside of your static dir (which is where in relation to your app.yaml file?), but no handlers for the specific css/js/img dirs? I still am having trouble getting it to work. I changed my handlers so I just had the static one. And then within the bit of html in my app file I used your code for the resource links, yet my local server tells me it gets 404 154 for each of the GET calls

Comment: Yes, I do not have specific handlers.  My app.yaml file and static folder are in the root application directory.

Comment: Mine are as well. Why isn't this working..........? could it have anything to do with the fact that my root app directory was created by virtualenv and that I run it locally as a virtual environment, but sync it to google as my normal ubuntu login (although bootstrap wont work locally or on appspot)

Comment: I have not used virtual environment with GAE.